# WP-JSON API request doesn't accept query parameters

Tags: wordpress, nginx

I am using the really great WP-API (https://github.com/WP-API/WP-API) to retrieve posts from my site. it works perfectly on my local dev environment (apache) and on an apache server. But on my future production server with nginx it doesn't.

http://2013.thomastraum.com/wp-json/posts

this query returns the only test post, which is the correct behaviour, but the query below won't work, all query parameters are ignored and it returns the same results as the above. The expected behaviour would be that it returns pages for example 'about' and 'contact' pages.

http://2013.thomastraum.com/wp-json/posts?type[]=page

you can see the correct query result here:

http://stage.thomastraum.com/wp-json/posts?type[]=page

As I said the only difference is the webserver. here is my nginx config file. my nginx version is `nginx/1.1.19`

```
server {
    # .domain.com will match both domain.com and anything.domain.com
    server_name 2013.thomastraum.com;

    # It is best to place the root of the server block at the server level, and not the location level
    # any location block path will be relative to this root. 
    root /var/www/2013.thomastraum.com;

    # It's always good to set logs, note however you cannot turn off the error log
    # setting error_log off; will simply create a file called 'off'.
    access_log /var/log/nginx/2013.thomastraum.com.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/2013.thomastraum.com.error.log;

    # This can also go in the http { } level
    index index.html index.htm index.php;

    location / { 
        # if you're just using wordpress and don't want extra rewrites
        # then replace the word @rewrites with /index.php
        # try_files $uri $uri/ index.php;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$request_uri;
    }

    location @rewrites {
        # Can put some of your own rewrite rules in here
        # for example rewrite ^/~(.*)/(.*)/? /users/$1/$2 last;
        # If nothing matches we'll just send it to /index.php
        rewrite ^ /index.php last;

    }

    # This block will catch static file requests, such as images, css, js
    # The ?: prefix is a 'non-capturing' mark, meaning we do not require
    # the pattern to be captured into $1 which should help improve performance
    location ~* \.(?:ico|css|js|gif|jpe?g|png)$ {
        # Some basic cache-control for static files to be sent to the browser
        expires max;
        add_header Pragma public;
        add_header Cache-Control "public, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate";
    }

    # remove the robots line if you want to use wordpress' virtual robots.txt
    location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }  

    # this prevents hidden files (beginning with a period) from being served
    location ~ /\.          { access_log off; log_not_found off; deny all; }

    location ~ \.php {
            fastcgi_param  QUERY_STRING       $query_string;
            fastcgi_param  REQUEST_METHOD     $request_method;
            fastcgi_param  CONTENT_TYPE       $content_type;
            fastcgi_param  CONTENT_LENGTH     $content_length;

            fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_NAME        $fastcgi_script_name;
            fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME    $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            fastcgi_param  REQUEST_URI        $request_uri;
            fastcgi_param  DOCUMENT_URI       $document_uri;
            fastcgi_param  DOCUMENT_ROOT      $document_root;
            fastcgi_param  SERVER_PROTOCOL    $server_protocol;

            fastcgi_param  GATEWAY_INTERFACE  CGI/1.1;
            fastcgi_param  SERVER_SOFTWARE    nginx;

            fastcgi_param  REMOTE_ADDR        $remote_addr;
            fastcgi_param  REMOTE_PORT        $remote_port;
            fastcgi_param  SERVER_ADDR        $server_addr;
            fastcgi_param  SERVER_PORT        $server_port;
            fastcgi_param  SERVER_NAME        $server_name;

            fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can fix the nginx.conf configuration file or alternatively you can append the GET parameter `json_route` in this fashion:

```
?json_route=/post
```

You also can do this with filters:

```
?json_route=/posts?filters[s]=something
```

Applied to your domain it looks like this:

- http://2013.thomastraum.com/?json_route=/post
- http://2013.thomastraum.com/?json_route=/posts?filters[s]=something

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @SidBurn - The links in this answer are not to external resources, but example URLs showing different paths.

Comment: You should probably rewrite your answer a little bit to make it more clear or provide a better answers. StackOverflow has a review system and answers from new users and so on gets reviewed, your comment looks like "Here look at that url, it shows how you do it." And "Philip Pittle" also reviewd your post and it looks he thinks your answer does not solve the problem.

Comment: hey thanks for the answer. Ideally I would like to fix the nginx problem. Your answer kind of works but for certain urls I get `502 bad gateway`... for example `http://2013.thomastraum.com/?json_route=/posts&type=tt_works` which I *think* means there must be a problem with nginx. I think you also have a typo in the url above: `http://2013.thomastraum.com/?json_route=/posts?filters[s]=something` which should be `http://2013.thomastraum.com/?json_route=/posts&filters[s]=something`

Comment: Actually I think I got the 502 because I had my query slightly wrong. It should still have returned an empty json array. So I guess this works, but the underlying problem is still the nginx conf from what I can tell. The current solution would also require me to change the api url between the dev and production which is not as ideal to just having to change the domain.

Answer (score 0):

The correct url should end with:

```
?json_route=/posts&filters[s]=something
```

Notice only a single question mark is used (multiple question marks are not valid urls), instead use an ampersand after the json_route=/posts

Answer (score 0):

*Notice only a single question mark is used (multiple question marks are not valid urls), instead use an ampersand after the json_route=/posts*

It is doesn't work for me.
When I use:
/?json_route=/posts&filter[search]=s
I got:
'filter[search]' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
When I use:
/?json_route=/posts?filter[search]=s
I got:
[{"code":"json_no_route","message":"No route was found matching the URL and request method"}]

Have you any decision for this issue.